# ¿Cómo puedo alinear las columnas al colocar setw en c++?

Tags: c++

Al imprimir 3 arreglos paralelos colocando una separación con `setw()` no se imprimen en la misma columna, quiero que todos queden alineados, aquí el código de ejemplo:

```
int main(){
    string nombre[5] = {"Charles Bukowski", "Ludwig von Mises", "Lucio Anneo Séneca", "H. P. Lovecraft", "George Orwell"};
    int puntaje[5] = {150, 15, 120, 1150, 700};
    string fecha[5] = {"19/8/1920", "19/9/1881", "4 a. C.", "20/8/1890", "26/6/1903"};

    cout << "Jugador" << setw(30) << "Puntaje" << setw(15) << "Fecha" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << nombre[i] << setw(30) << puntaje[i] << setw(15) << fecha[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como se observa en el código, la distancia entre la descripción de la columna antes del `for` con `setw()` y al imprimir los arreglos son las mismas, este es el resultado obtenido:

[image: Ejemplo setw() en c++]

Como observan, aunque tenga la misma separación en los `setw()`, se imprimen desalineados con respecto a la columna, ¿conocen alguna solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en la forma de como ordenas los `setw()`

Por ejemplo en esta linea de código defines tus columnas:

```
cout << "Jugador" << setw(30) << "Puntaje" << setw(15) << "Fecha" << endl;
```

Esta forma de proceder no esta correcta puesto que la columna jugador no esta definida.

Antes de definir tus columnas decide primero el ancho que tendrá cada una y luego su alineación (left o right) y ten en cuenta que si tenes una columna con alineación en right y luego la que sigue en left deja una tabulador de separacion o los espacios en blancos que necesites

Por ejemplo:

1. **Jugador**. Ancho de Columna **25**, Alineación **left**, Margen entre columnas,**left(2, "| "), right(1, "|")**
2. **Puntaje**. Ancho de Columna **15**, Alineación **right**, Margen entre columnas ,**left(0), right(3, " | ")**
3. **Fecha**. Ancho de Columna **12**, Alineación **left**, Margen entre columnas,**left(0), right(1, "|")**

Al final el código quedaría asi

```
string nombre[5] =
 {
    "Charles Bukowski",
    "Ludwig von Mises",
    "Lucio Anneo Séneca",
    "H. P. Lovecraft",
    "George Orwell"
 };
 int puntaje[5] = { 150, 15, 120, 1150, 700 };
 string fecha[5] = 
 { "19/8/1920", "19/9/1881", "4 a. C.", "20/8/1890", "26/6/1903" };
 cout << setw( 60 ) << setfill( '-' ) << '\n' << setfill( ' ' );
 cout << "| "
      << left << setw( 25 ) << "Jugador"
      << "|"
      << right << setw( 15 ) << "Puntaje"
      << " | "
      << left << setw( 12 ) << "Fecha"
      << "|";
    cout << setw( 60 ) << setfill( '-' ) << '\n' << setfill( ' ' ) << '\n';
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        cout << "| "
             << setw( 25 ) << nombre[i]
             << "|"
             << right << setw( 15 ) << puntaje[i]
             << " | "
             << left << setw( 12 ) << fecha[i]
             << "|"
             << endl;
    }
    cout << setw( 60 ) << setfill( '-' ) << '-' << setfill( ' ' );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Codigo]